# I want to use my own image as model in AR app in runtime — is that possible?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am using Unity and Vuforia for my AR app and need to add my own image as model — is that possible at run time?
My app creates a diagram and in next step I want show that diagram on my user define target in AR. Any key? Or idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you save the digram as a sprite/image, you can place it at the location where the marker is detected by Vuforia using the callbacks provided by Vuforia when it detects a marker.